# Why does `assoc' return nil in this case?

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I am trying to write a Export Backend for Emacs org-mode. This mode is derived from the *ox-latex.el* Exporter. I want the Exporter to embed all *.css and *.js files into the resulting .html file.

The Exporter runs but does'nt give any output in my functions, because this

`assoc(t (("readthedocs" ("css" "htmlize.css" "readtheorg.css") ("js" "readtheorg.js" "jquery.js" "bootstrap.js"))))`

call (it's from the debugger) returns nil.

What am I missing here ?

Any help appreciated :) Full Code can be found here https://pastebin.com/N475Uk9Z

**EDIT:**

```
(defconst org-static-html-themes
  '(("readthedocs" . (("css" . ("htmlize.css"
                                "readtheorg.css"))
                      ("js" . ("readtheorg.js"
                               "jquery.js"
                               "bootstrap.js"))))))

(defun org-static-html--build-head (info)
  "Return information for the <head>..</head> of the HTML output.
INFO is a plist used as a communication channel."
  (progn
    (debug)

    (org-element-normalize-string
     (concat
      (org-element-normalize-string (plist-get info :html-head))
      (org-element-normalize-string (plist-get info :html-head-extra))
      (org-element-normalize-string
       (mapconcat (lambda (css)
                    (org-static-html-inline-css
                     (concat org-static-html-resource-path "/css/" css)))
                  (cdr (assoc "css"
                              (assoc
                               (plist-get info :static-html-theme)
                               org-static-html-themes))) "\n"))))))
```

This function is supposed to get all css files associated with the corresponding theme and return then concatenated and wrapped inside style tags.

I should say that I'm using Emacs version 27.0.50.

Comment: It's not clear what you expected/wanted it to return in this case.  Could you elaborate on which data you're trying to get back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your association list contains just one association: between `"readthedocs"` and `(("css" "htmlize.css" "readtheorg.css") ("js" "readtheorg.js" "jquery.js" "bootstrap.js"))`.
Since nothing is associated with `t`, `(assoc t ...)` returns `nil`.

Comment: I didn't associate anything with `t` that's true, but i didn't want to get that either. The first Code snippet was copied out of the debugger window.

Comment: Ahh i have found the problem, the plist-get does not return a string in my case so i need to fix this. So you are right.